# Passing redirect-param in faces-config in jsf-2.2

Tags: navigation, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4, mojarra, faces-config

In old jsf the following code was working

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/page1.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/page2.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <view-param>
                <name>id</name>
                <value>#{myBean.id}</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

page1.xhtml code :

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="id" name="id" value="#{myBean.id}"  />
    <f:viewAction action="#{myBean.init()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Java code :

```
public class MyBean(){
   private double id;

   public boolean init(){
      if(id > 0)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
}
```

In the success scenario when `page1.xhtml?id=0` page1 will be opened while `page1.xhtml?id=1` navigation to `page2` with parameter `id=1`.

navigation to `page2.xhtml?id=1` with parameter is needed since in `page2` on `PostConstruct` or `<f:viewAction>` parameter is read and needed to find object according to this id

Using jsf 2.2 with mojarra javax.faces-2.2.8 implementation in faces-config.xml file there is no `<view-param>` there is `<redirect-param>` changing them gives no success scenario where navigation is without id where it will navigate to `page2.xhtml` instead of `page2.xhtml?id=1`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the old way. Instead of using `<redirect-param>` use `<view-param>`. The xsd (http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd) will mark it as false but mojarra javax.faces-2.2.8 will silently use it the right way you want it.

Edit: The XSD will be fixed in the Mojarra 2.3 release, see the other 'answer'

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd" version="2.2">
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            ...
            <redirect>
                <view-param>
                    <name>foo</name>
                    <value>bar</value>
                </view-param>
            </redirect>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `include-view-params="true"` attribute in `<redirect>` element of `faces-config.xml` instead of declaring parameters using `<view-param>` tag.
Also be sure to declare `<f:viewParam>` in the target page (`page2.xhtml`).
I believe I made your example work as you expected like this:
**Navigation rule in faces-config.xml:**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/page1.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/page2.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect include-view-params="true" />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

**page1.xhtml code (unchanged):**

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="id" name="id" value="#{myBean.id}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{myBean.init()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

**page2.xhtml code:**

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="id" name="id"/>
</f:metadata>
```

**ManagedBean (unchanged):**

```
public class MyBean {
    private double id;

    public boolean init(){
        if(id > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    // getter & setter for id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the old `<view-param>` tag on configuration, as Jaxt0r mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34773335/2521247

This is a bug on JSF that is fixed for 2.3. See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3403